# "Ich habe Hunger" or "Ich bin hungrig"?

Tags: meaning, usage

A student of mine was told by a native German that they do not say

> Ich habe Hunger.

but rather

> Ich bin hungrig.

Is the first expression outdated?

Comment: manchal höre ich auch das Verb https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/verhungern wie z.B "Ich verhungere!"

Answer (score 15):

*Ich habe Hunger* is perfectly acceptable on all levels of conversation and used without afterthought as a viable alternative to *Ich bin hungrig*. The former is neither outdated, nor inappropriate in any way.

This is based on the experience of a German native to eastern Germany.

Using [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ich%20habe%20Hunger%2C%20Ich%20bin%20hungrig&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIch%20habe%20Hunger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIch%20bin%20hungrig%3B%2Cc0), it appears that *Ich habe Hunger* is in fact more commonly used than the alternative, having significantly increased in relative popularity since the 1970s.

[image: Comparison of phrase usage from Google nGrams]

Answer (score 8):

As already told both expressions are used. However, there's a difference. *»Ich habe Hunger«* always refers to food, *»Ich bin hungrig«* not necessarily, it can mean *»I'm ambitious«*.

A person also can be

> hungrig nach Liebe / Anerkennung / Abenteuern ...
>   *(hungry for love / acceptance / adventures ...)*

Comment: Also, 'ich habe (mal wieder) Hunger auf Fisch' can mean that the speaker craves fish, and not necessarily that he is in fact hungry.

Comment: @PhilippFlenker: Wenn mir einer sagt _»Ich habe (mal wieder) Hunger auf Fisch«_, würde ich das schon so verstehen, dass er essen will, und ihm erwidern: _»Du, ich hab jetzt keinen hier.«_

Comment: @PhilippFlenker: if I wanted to express what you're suggesting I'd say:"Ich hátte mal wieder Lust auf Fisch".

Answer (score 5):

No, the first expression is not outdated. Both expressions are used in common conversations. Both expressions have the same meaning and can changed among themselves.